# bash printf escaping format (%q) in xargs

Tags: bash, shell, printf, xargs

Consider the bash commands executed below.

For the reference from `man xargs`:

> -t, --verbose
>          Print the command line on the standard error output before executing it.

```
# `printf` (1)
echo "meeny miny moe" | xargs -t -I {} printf "%q " "{}"
printf %q  meeny miny moe
'meeny miny moe'

# Then let's try the command output by `xargs`
printf %q  meeny miny moe
meenyminymoe

# `printf` (2)
echo "meeny miny moe" | xargs -t -I {} sh -c 'printf "%q " "$@"' -- "{}"
sh -c printf "%q " "$@" -- meeny miny moe
meeny\ miny\ moe

# Then let's try the command output by `xargs`
sh -c printf "%q " "$@" -- meeny miny moe
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

# `printf` (3)
printf "%q " "meeny miny moe"
meeny\ miny\ moe
```

Ok, (2) is equivalent to (3), both make sense to me. I have a few questions.

**Question 1**
Why `xargs` outputs a wrong command with `-t`: executing this command produces totally different result from the actual `xargs` execution? What is missing there, what `xargs` is not printing?

**Question 2**
Why the result from (1) is different from results in (2) and (3)? Is it `xargs` which single quotes the resulting output, or is it `printf` by some reason is doing that?

Replace `%q` with `%s` and

```
echo "meeny miny moe" | xargs -t -I {} printf "%s " "{}"
printf %s  meeny miny moe
meeny miny moe
```

the result is different, so I assume it is not `xargs` is quoting the output, is it `printf`? How can I achieve the same result only with `printf` without `xargs`? Why `printf` behaves like this only with `xargs`?

Comment: What does `sh -c 'printf "%q" "a b c"'` output on your system? How about `bash -c 'printf "%q" "a b c"'`?

Comment: @melpomene Both output `a\ b\ c`.

Comment: Ah. Built-in `printf` vs. program `printf`, not different shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

When printing the command, `xargs` omits the quotes. It should have written:

```
printf "%q " "meeny miny moe"
```

Without the quotes, you got:

```
printf %q  meeny miny moe
```

(notice the two space characters)

### Question 2

`printf %q` outputs in 1) and 2) are different but they are both correct.

The difference is that in 1) you are using the `printf` executable (probably in `/usr/bin`, and in 2) you are using the `printf` builtin provided by your shell.

Try it:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "meeny miny moe"
meeny\ miny\ moe

$ /usr/bin/printf '%q\n' "meeny miny moe"
'meeny miny moe'

$ command printf '%q\n' "meeny miny moe"
meeny\ miny\ moe
```